# Can I use npm package docusign-click in a React application?

Tags: reactjs, docusignapi, react-dom

Can I use the docusign-click npm package in React to render without importing using a script tag?

for now I am using the script to show the click wrap like this

```
window.docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render(
    {
      agreementUrl: contractUrl,
      environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
         accountId, //is this mandatory?
         clickwrapId, //is this mandatory?
         clientUserId: userId, //is this mandatory?
      onAgreed: () => {
        console.log('USER AGREED');
      },
      onDeclined: () => {
        console.log('USER DECLINED');
      },
    },
    '#docu-sign',
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a server package that is needed to manage the Clickwraps using the DocuSign Click API. Not sure what you're trying to do, but React for the front-end usually won't need to use the docusign-click npm package on the client if you just want to show the clickwrap for the user.

Comment: So I got this URL https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/XXXX that is generated per user, and I want to render it and manage some events such as onAgreed and onDeclined, I am using Clickwrap.render and passing the variables agreementUrl and environment what other variables are mandatory? To be honest the documentation is not so helpful. I couldnt find anything on onAgreed and onDeclined and agreementUrl except on stackoverflow.

Comment: yes, these are client side events and we don't currently have documentation or packages for them.